# Strictly increasing function and derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f'(x) \geq 0$ is valid for all $x \in [a,b]$. Now suppose that $f'(x) = 0$ for a finite number of values in $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is a strictly increasing function.

---

**My Proof**:

Let $M=\{x \in [a,b] \text{ | }f'(x) = 0\}$ be a finite set.

Let $u,v \in [a,b]$ with $u<v$. It follows that:

$ f(u)\leq f(z) \leq f(v) \text{ } \forall z \in [u,v]\subset[a,b]$ because $f'(x) \geq 0$.

Now suppose that $f(u)=f(v)$. Therefore $f'(x) = 0 $ in $[u,v]  \forall x$, hence $[u,v] \subset M$, which is a contradiction because we supposed that $M$ is finite. Therefore $f(u) < f(v)$.

---

Can someone please check my work? Thanks!

Comment: While it is "clear" (and straighforward) that $f'(u)\ge0$ for all $u\in [x,y]$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ together imply $f'(u)=0$ for all $u\in[x,y]$, I wonder if you have an explicit result saying so available for this exercise

Comment: The proof makes complete sense!

Comment: You should make it a question asked and answered by yourself actually